# PHP Check If String Contains Numbers and Check String Length

Tags: php, numeric

I'm trying to check if a username string is all numbers (but the field is not a numeric field).  If so, I need the string to be 5 characters in length by adding leading 0's.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$getuname = $_GET['un'];

if (mb_strlen($getuname) <= 1){
        $getuname = "0".$getuname;
    }
if (mb_strlen($getuname) <= 2){
        $getuname = "0".$getuname;
    }
if (mb_strlen($getuname) <= 3){
        $getuname = "0".$getuname;
    }
if (mb_strlen($getuname) <= 4){
        $getuname = "0".$getuname;
    }   
echo $getuname;
?>
```

The above code works for making sure the string is 5 characters by adding zeros, but it's not very pretty and I'm sure there is a much nicer way to do it.  Anyone?

Also, this whole piece needs to be wrapped in an IF statement that is checking to see if it contains nothing but numbers in the first place.  I tried using !is_numeric, but this doesn't seem to work. I'm assuming because it's not a numeric type field.

Comment: use `preg_match` to check if the username contains only numbers http://es1.php.net/preg_match

Comment: tas9 is completely right, preg_match is the best solution to check that. is_int and is_numeric are not reliable in this case.

Comment: FYI: For a speed test over 1 million reps, `ctype_digit` took 0.114777s, regex solution took 0.783449s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can** use `is_numeric` to check for a numeric field, it doesn't matter whether the variable is a string or not. [See example here.](https://eval.in/98721)

Then you can simply pad using `str_pad()`

```
if(!is_numeric($test))
    echo $test . ' is not a number!';
else
    echo str_pad($test, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

**Edit:** as flixer pointed out, `is_numeric()` won't actually do what you specifically asked (to check that a string contains only digits, i.e. no periods, commas, dashes etc which would be considered to "be a number"). In this case, use `ctype_digit()` instead:

```
$test_number = '123.4';
$test_number2 = '12345';

echo ctype_digit($test_number) ? $test_number . ' is only digits' : $test_number . ' is not only digits';
echo ctype_digit($test_number2) ? $test_number2 . ' is only digits' : $test_number2 . ' is not only digits';

// output:
// 123.4 is not only digits
// 12345 is only digits
```

The key here is to [avoid regex when you have better tools to do the job.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243)

To add a little to this, `ctype_digit()` might return **false** when you pass in an integer variable: (example from PHP manual)

```
ctype_digit( '42' ); // true
ctype_digit( 42 ); // false - ASCII 42 is the * symbol
```

This can be OK, depending on the situation you're using this in. In your case you're validating a `$_GET` variable, which is always going to be a string so it won't affect you.

**Docs:**

- `str_pad()`: http://php.net/str_pad
- `ctype_digit()`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

OP Here, this is it all together.  Works like a charm...

```
   if (ctype_digit($getuname) == true) {
    $getuname = str_pad($getuname, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

Comment: "is_numeric" is not a good solution for check whether a string contains only numbers because it will return true on cases like '5.1', '-3' and '1e7'

Answer (score 2):

Use the [str_pad()](http://php.net/str_pad) function. Like this:

```
$getuname = str_pad($_GET['un'], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$getuname = $_GET['un'];
if(ctype_digit($getuname))
     $getuname = str_repeat("0", 5-strlen($getuname)) . $getuname;
?>
```

Hope it works for u.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a clean solution:

```
$getuname = $_GET['un'];
if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$getuname)){
    echo sprintf('%05d', $getuname);
}else{
    // incorrect format
}
```

Comment: No need to use regex here.

Comment: Why not? What is your preferred solution for checking whether "I'm trying to check if a username string is all numbers"

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$getuname = $_GET['un'];


while (strlen($getuname) < 5) {
    $getuname = '0' . $getuname;
}

echo $getuname;

?>
```